# Access batch file dirrectory inside sed script file

Tags: windows, sed, cmd

I am writing some scripts that will compile a simple markup language I made up into a latex document. I use a Batch script to run a GNUSed script and compile the resulting LaTeX. In the Sed script I have some code that inserts the text from a file `preamblelatex.txt` into a marked location:

```
/insertpreamble/ {
    r preamblelatex.txt
    s:insertpreamble:\n:
}
```

*The problem is:* When I run the script outside of the directory in which my batch script resides, `r preablelatex.txt` looks for `preamblelatex.txt` in the working directory. I can't hardcode the filepath into the Sed script because I'm going to be sharing this code with some friends. Also, my Sed commands need to all be contained within one script file or I will run into all kinds of problems overwriting stuff. Is there any way to pass the directory in which the Batch script resides into the Sed script and reference it inside the Sed code?

Comment: Can't you just set the current directory to the directory of `preamblelatex.txt` within your batch file just bebore calling sed ? Or maybe call the batch file through its relative or absolute path from the preamble directory ? It may help to see a pruned version of your batch file.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think to just change the working directory. Thanks Luciole.